# Menor elemento de uma sub-lista, em um lista

Tags: python-3.x, matriz, lista

Estou tentando aplicar a heurística em um código que venho trabalhando atualmente, mas preciso obter o menor elemento de uma sub-lista, de um lista. exemplo:

```
L = [[1, 1, 6], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 7],
     [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 9], [2, 3, 4],
     [3, 1, 5], [3, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Para cada uma das sub-listas L[ ][0] e L[ ][1] são coordenadas x e y (Os dois primeiros elementos das sub-lista são x e y) , e o L[ ][2] (Terceiro elemento) são os valores que preciso verificar. Como posso verificar todas as sub-lista, e retornar o com menor L[ ][2]? Que nesse exemplo é L[3][2].

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o que precisa fazer. O que são `x` e `y`? Por quê o resultado deve ser `L[3][2]`? Esse valor será o último 1 da sub-lista `[2, 1, 1]`. É isso mesmo?

Comment: x e y são os dois primeiros valores de cada sublista,  e o resultado que procurava era o menor terceiro elemento, entre todas as sublistas. Nesse caso o resultado deverá ser L[3][2], pois de todas as sublistas, o terceiro elemento da quarta sublista, e o menor valor, em relação ao das outras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Código**

```
k = 0
for (i, sublista) in enumerate(L):
    if sublista[2] < L[k][2]:
        k = i
# indice da lista (L) que contem o menor L[][3]
print(k)
```

**Explicação**

A variável `k` irá armazenar  o índice da lista `L` que contem o menor terceiro elemento. Como inicialmente não sabemos qual o índice, iremo setar o índice inicial, no caso, `0`.

Com isso usamos uma estrutura de repetição (`for in`) para percorrer a variável `L`, onde a variável `i` irá receber o índice da sublista de `L`, e `sublista` irá conter a sublista pertencente a `L[i]`.

Tendo isso, basta fazer um `if` para verificar se a posição 3 da sublista atual (`sublista[2]`) é menor que a posição 3 da sublista que temos o índice salvo (`L[k][2]`), se for menor, basta fazer com que `k` receba o valor do índice atual, `i`.